# update foreign key using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

i am trying to update foreign key in a table named(Friendship).The foreign key is of the table named(FriendshipStatus) the problem is that all the values are updated except the foreign key. I m using code first approach.

Friendship Class

```
public class Friendship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User UserOne { get; set; }
    public User UserTwo { get; set; }
    public FriendshipStatus Status { get; set; }
    public User ReqSB { get; set; }
    public RelationType RelationType { get; set; }
    public Relationship Relationship { get; set; }
    public DateTime FriendshipDate { get; set; }



}
```

FriendshipStatus class

```
public class FriendshipStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code for update

```
 using (context)
        {


            Friendship f = getFrienshipRecord(u1, u2); // get single record from db which is to be updated
            if (f != null)
            {
                Friendship ff = new Friendship();
                ff.Status = new FriendshipStatus() { Id = 2}; //actually wants to update this this field
                ff.Id = f.Id;
                ff.FriendshipDate = DateTime.Now;

                context.Entry(ff).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();


            }

        }
```

The above code changes datetime but it does not change foreign key.

Comment: You need to update the state of FriendshipStatus to modified as well. Another way is to just update the record you fetched (f) instead of creating a new instance and setting its state.

Comment: can you please show me sample code that how can i update the state of FriendshipStatus to modified. i have tried the other way without creating new instance but same problem. @SteveGreene

Answer (score 2):

This is the technique I use for updates that include a child. First, I like to expose the Foreign Key as part of the parent. If you name it FriendshipStatusId, EF will make the association automatically or you can add an annotation or fluent code if preferred:

```
public class Friendship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User UserOne { get; set; }
    public User UserTwo { get; set; }

    public int? FriendshipStatusId { get; set; }  // optional FK
    public FriendshipStatus Status { get; set; }

    public User ReqSB { get; set; }
    public RelationType RelationType { get; set; }
    public Relationship Relationship { get; set; }
    public DateTime FriendshipDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do your update by simply fetching the entity (which puts it under tracking) and updating the FK:

```
using (context)
{
    Friendship f = getFrienshipRecord(u1, u2); // get single record from db which is to be updated
    if (f != null)
    {
        f.FriendshipDate = DateTime.Now;
        f.FriendshipStatusId = 2;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Note that if you add the FK you may need to do a migration or regenerate your database because the EF default might be something like FriendshipStatus_Id.

Comment: Is'nt there any simple way to do that ? why is it so complex :(

Comment: There are different ways to do it. Simpler is subjective. We do a few things different than the code above. You can [inject](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) the context, you can use [Automapper](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-framework-and-wcf-mapping-entities-to-dtos-with-automapper/) to update the entity from the viewmodel, etc. What part(s) are you looking to simplify?